# jquery handle ajax response outside of ajax object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with jQuery and I need to handle the data gathered during an AJAX call outside of the AJAX object:

```
function getData(yt_url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            //   Return response here //

        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to call the function `getData` and receive the response object in the AJAX success function.

I've tried adding some returns and then of course I realized it was an object.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so it does not block the execution of the script. Returning a value like that is synchronous, which is incompatible with AJAX. A solution would be to pass a function into `getData` that gets called when the AJAX request finishes.

Comment: Thatnks, that was it. Post it as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, which basically means that it does not block the execution of the script (which is good, as your website does not freeze while things load).

`return`ing a value like you're doing is synchronous, which is incompatible with AJAX.

One solution would be to pass a callback function into `getData` that gets called when the AJAX request finishes:

```
function getData(yt_url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: callback,
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}​
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
getData('http://www.example.com/', function(response) {
    alert('The response was: ' + response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this - add a global variable that will store the result of the ajax call, for example

```
var ajaxResult = null;
```

set ajax's *async* property to **false** and then write something like this:

```
var ajaxResult = null;

function getData(yt_url){
$.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
                        url: yt_url,
                        dataType:"jsonp",
                        async: false,
                        success: function(response){
                            ajaxResult = response; 

                        },error:function (request, status, error)           
});
```

}

getData(yt_url); // call the function to try to get the result
if(ajaxResult != null){ // if we got some result during the ajax call

```
    // do something with the result
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since AJAX is asynchronous, you should restructure your code to receive the data in a callback function. Whenever the request is finished, you then can continue with whatever you wanted to do with the data. An example:

```
$.ajax {
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: success,
    error: error
};

function success(data) {
    // continue your work here.
}

function error(request, status, error) {
    // handle any errors here.
}
```

I would not recommend using `async: false`, since it freezes the browser until it finishes executing your request, while in general you might like it to remain responsive while it processes your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this fits for any of you, but what i did in my case is, I stored the response data in "localSotrage" of browser and later used that "localSotrage" data in other usual javascript function !! Give it a try if it fulfills your purpose !!

Also let me know, if this approach has some negative impacts !!

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax is async by default. Use async : false to disable it.

```
    function getData(yt_url){
        var data;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
                        async: false,
                        url: yt_url,
                        dataType:"jsonp",success: function(response){
                            //   Return response here //
                            // init data variable
                        },error:function (request, status, error) {alert(status);}
                    });
         return data;
   }
```

Comment: What about a callback function instead?

Comment: To clarify, async: false is discontinued functionality in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the `get`-function asynchronous and use `await` to wait for the response:

```js
async function getData(yt_url, callback) {
    return await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: callback,
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}​

getData().then(response => console.log(response)); // `getData` will return a promise

// But you can use await for `getData()` in another `async function`:
async function useData() {
    const data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
}
```